# How to allow file in windows virus and threat protection in Windows Server Core

Tags: anti-virus, windows-server-core, windows-server-2022

In Windows Server 2022 with GUI, when Windows Security incorrect detect file as virus and threat and quarantined threat, I can allowed threats from Windows Security settings.

But I do not know how to doing this in Windows Core?

I need allowed specific threat in windows Server core 2022

If any one provide some powershell command for this, I very welocome, for example in powershell, if you want to disable real time monitoring, you just says `Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $true` and know I need to command to allowed specific threats